# This database is not enabled for publication

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
USE GlobalSales;
GO

EXEC sp_helpmergepublication GlobalSales
EXEC sp_helppublication GlobalSales
EXEC sp_helppublication_snapshot GlobalSales
GO

-- Execute this batch at the Publisher.
DECLARE @publication AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriptionDB AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriber AS sysname;
SET @publication = N'Mitjab-Notebook\SQL2008'; 
SET @subscriptionDB = N'GlobalSales'; 
SET @subscriber = N'SERVER\SQL2008';

-- At the Publisher, register the subscription, using the defaults.
USE [GlobalSales]
EXEC sp_addsubscription 
    @publication = @publication, 
    @subscriber = @subscriber, 
    @destination_db = @subscriptionDB, 
    @subscription_type = N'pull', 
    @update_mode = N'failover';
GO
```

but i get:

Msg 14013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_helppublication_snapshot, Line 29
This database is not enabled for publication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do replication (as publisher) with the Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

So then enable publication, or run this on the database which is enabled for publication.  Take a look in the replication options to configure publication and distribution.